# What is the best way to build JQuery mobile custom components

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I am working on a experiment of making JQuery mobile custom components with JQuery tmpl(Templating plugin). The component are building using existing JQuerymobile items and also they are programmatic components. I am using plain `JavaScript` functions and prototypes to create these components. The purpose behind this and I wanted to made a component that can be easily generate pragmatically, i.e`var myAccordian = new Accordian()`  like that.

So is there a more structured way of doing these components(can say widgets) and also the event binding for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile component is created using the $.widget () method defined internally in jQuery Mobile. This method allows to create and initialize the component and add any specific methods.

There are multiple tutorials available which explains the process such as

1. https://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2011/11/07/how-to-write-a-custom-widget-for-jquery-mobile/
2. http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH09.php